# Como Definir Tamanhos diferentes do "Row" no Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

estou com dúvida de como definir um valor de 100% width (preenchendo toda a tela, independente do container) apenas para uma "Row" do bootstrap, é necessário criar uma nova classe css para essa row em especifico? tem uma maneira + fácil de conseguir?

Agradeço quem puder me ajudar

[image: Exemplo]

Comment: Amigo acho que o row já é 100% porém ele é 100% relativo ao elemento que limita a largura. Não é bem o row que você quer alterar.

Comment: Ao lado de cada resposta tem um *check* para marcar a que resolver seu problema. Não é preciso mudar o título da pergunta. Conheça nosso [tour]

Answer (score 2):

Amigo, você pode usar o .container-fluid

Exemplo:

[Visualizar Código](http://www.bootply.com/WpYgPgBZ4W)

a partir desse conceito você vai criando seu layout.

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer que fique 100% apenas em um determinado row sugiro que faça algo do tipo:

```
'.row .row-100'
```

por que assim você estaria adicionando a propriedade `width:100%` apenas para aquele row especifico. Sempre pense de forma escalavél, o quanto vou ré-usar, se é algo especifico, prefira criar uma classe nova.

Answer (score 0):

Caros Colegas, consegui resolver meu problema utilizando a seguinte estrutura:

container (para o conteúdo fixo centralizado)

container-fluid (para deixar 100% widht) e dentro dele outro container (para colocar o conteúdo centralizado :)

Ex.:

```
<div class="container">
   Conteúdo
</div>


<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
       conteúdo
    </div>
</div>
```